# Configure Rails console's default date time format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

By default, our Rails application displays date time like this

> Sun, 08 Jan 2023 16:52:46.610977000 UTC +00:00

This is also shown in Rails console, when a time object is inspected.

Is it possible to set a different date time format, just for the Rails console alone?

Answer (score 2):

That format is the output from [`TimeWithZone#inspect`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-inspect), which is hard-coded:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb, line 150
def inspect
  "#{time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%9N')} #{zone} #{formatted_offset}"
end
```

Rails however provides a `console` block to register code which gets only executed when running the Rails console (casually mentioned in the docs for [`config.console`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-console)). You could use it to provide your own `inspect` method while running console, e.g.:

```
# config/application.rb

module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    console do
      # this block is called only when running console

      class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
        def inspect
          time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

```
$ bin/rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.6)
irb(main):001:0> Time.current
=> 2023-07-20 12:36:10
```

Other rails execution contexts are not affected:

```
$ bin/rails runner 'p Time.current'
Thu, 20 Jul 2023 12:38:47.934270000 CEST +02:00
```

Note that [`Time.current`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-current) is a Rails method which (usually) returns an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, not an instance of Ruby's built-in `Time` class.

Although Rails doesn't change `Time#inspect`, it alters the `inspect` methods for Ruby's built-in classes `Date` and `DateTime` to make them more readable, see [`core_ext/date/conversions.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.6/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/conversions.rb#L61-L66) and [`core_ext/date_time/conversions.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.6/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/conversions.rb#L55-L60). If needed, you can provide your own `inspect` implementation for console use by patching those classes as well.

But keep in mind that patching classes and altering existing behavior always comes at the risk of breaking something.

Comment: Thanks! This works for `User.last.created_at`. However I want to point out that at least in Rails 7 this does not cover `DateTime` and `Time`, so your example may be misleading. `DateTime` and `Time` does not seem to inherit `ActiveSupporet::TimeWithZone`.

Comment: @lulalala because of the specific format in your question, I assumed that you only wanted to change the output for `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. I've updated my answer to also cover the built-in classes `Time`, `Date` and `DateTime`.